# sql server. Посчитать сколько раз подряд встречается символ в строке

Tags: sql-server

Допустим есть число 144578444, нужно вывести значение максимальной последовательности цифры 4, то есть 3.

Comment: А при чём тут SQL Server для решения такой задачи?

Comment: @NowhereMan я пытаюсь выполнить это в этой субд

Comment: В рекурсивном CTE поделите число на отдельные цифры, сохраняя и позицию. Затем оконными функциями пронумеруйте их в слитной группе с последовательными номерами. Ну и финально выведите запись с максимальным номером.

Comment: Возможно, задача совсем простая: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860457/how-to-count-instances-of-character-in-sql-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH 
cte1 AS (  -- исходное число
  SELECT CAST(14455578444 AS BIGINT) AS data  
),
cte2 AS (  -- делим на отдельные цифры
  SELECT CAST(data / 10 AS BIGINT) AS data, data % 10 AS digit, LEN(CAST(data AS CHAR)) AS position
  FROM cte1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT data / 10, data % 10, position - 1
  FROM cte2
  WHERE data > 0
),
cte3 AS (  -- делим на слитные группы
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY position) rn1,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY digit ORDER BY position) rn2
  FROM cte2
)
  -- считаем и выводим сведения о самых длинных группах
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
       digit, MIN(position) position, COUNT(*) amount
FROM cte3
GROUP BY digit, (rn1 - rn2)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

| digit | position | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 9 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HIg9Tldi)

Comment: большое спасибо!